# Can we use a constructed dynamic jQuery selector?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to contruct a jquery selector as a string and pass its value to the selector.

```
$(document).on( 'keyup', function( e ) {
    if( e.keyCode == 9 ) {
        //console.log( e.target );

        console.log(e.target.id);

        var preTabIndex = document.getElementById(e.target.id).tabIndex;
        var nextTabIndex = preTabIndex + 1;

        console.log(preTabIndex);
        console.log(nextTabIndex);

        //console.log($('[tabindex=3]')[0].id);

        var selector = "[tabindex=" + nextTabIndex + "]";

        console.log(selector);
        console.log($(selector)[0].Id);

        //document.getElementById($("[tabindex=3]")[0].id).focus();
        document.getElementById($(selector)[0].id).focus();
    }
} );
```

Can this be done? I couldn't find it on my initial googling.

With this i am getting an undefined when i do

```
console.log($(selector)[0].Id);
```

Comment: Would it have taken that long to have tested it yourself? Yes, it can be done.

Comment: This... I can't see why you do that : `document.getElementById($(selector)[0].id).focus();`...

Comment: `document.getElementById($(selector)[0].id).focus();` is the same as `$(selector)[0].focus();`

Comment: Have you tried `console.log($(selector)[0].id);`? Mind the lowercase i in `id`.

Comment: Yes, May be i wasn't clear with what i wanted to ask, I have edited my question

Comment: @ArtjomB. It's *mostly* the same as `$(selector).focus()`...

Comment: You have to replicate your issue somewhere we can check it. Maybe your selector just return an empty object or this element doesn't have any attribute ID, who knows... But answer to your question is, of course you can

Comment: Well this is a bit embaressing, can't believe that i missed the difference between `Id` and `id`, but thanks everyone for the replies

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can. Make sure you use the . or # to denote the target. For example,

In your HTML:

```
<p id="header">hello</p>
```

In your JS:

```
var my_selector = "#header";
$(my_selector).html('wow');
```

Comment: Yes, this is correct, but in the example he's looking to select elements by attributes.

Comment: Forgive my ignorance, but is the "[tabindex=3" a valid syntax? Thanks.

Comment: Yes `$("[attr=value]")` is perfectly valid and appears to be what he's trying to do, but dynamically.  He's fixed the issue anyway.  It was a typo.  He was trying to get `Id` instead of `id`.

Comment: Here you go... https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes#tabindex